# Django: django-admin startproject ImportError

Tags: python, django

I have two Python VE's one in which I created a Django project that is located on the Desktop. I recently created another VE to start another Django project. However, when I run `django-admin startproject projectname` within the new VE, I get an ImportError saying that the other Django app couldn't be imported.

What would be trying to import my old app? Why would this be happening?

I am running Django 1.9 on Debian 8.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/lie/.virtualenvs/tagger/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'AUVSIDataProc'
```

Comment: what about : **django-admin.py startproject mysite** ??? with a different location for the new project

Comment: Still got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found there was an Environment Variable called `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

I just unset it: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=""`. and I was able to start a new project.